# called CSV colum into java program using array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, arraylist

Here is the code:

```
private static void readInput(String arr[], List<Table> tables) {
    if (arr.length < 4 || !arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("select") || !arr[2].equalsIgnoreCase("from")
        || !String.valueOf(arr[arr.length - 1].charAt(arr[arr.length - 1].length() - 1)).equals(";")) {
      System.out.println("Output : SQL Error (Syntax Error)");
      return;
    }


    if (arr.length == 4) {
      Table table = searchTable(arr[3], tables);
      if (table == null) {
        System.out.println("Output : SQL Error (Table Not Found)");
        return;
      }

      if (arr[1].equals("*")) {
        System.out.println("Tabel \t: " + table.getName());
        System.out.print("List Kolom \t:");
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumns().length; i++) {
          String s = table.getColumns()[i];
          System.out.print(s);
          if (i != table.getColumns().length - 1)
            System.out.print(",");
        }
        System.out.println();
      } else {
        String selColumns[] = arr[1].split(",");
        boolean first = true;

        System.out.println("Tabel \t\t: " + table.getName());
        System.out.print("List Kolom \t: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < selColumns.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumns().length; j++) {
            if (selColumns[i].equals(table.getColumns()[i])) {
              if (first) {
                System.out.print(selColumns[i]);
                first = false;
                break;
              } else {
                System.out.print("," + selColumns[i]);
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

table :

Member,member_id,nama,telp

Meminjam,id_buku,id_member,durasi;

Buku,id_buku,judul,genre;

This program is for checking the sql statement's. It parse a data from CSV file. The problem is when I select more than 2 columns, example like when I select id_member from member, it will show name of the table and (attributes)columns. However, when I try to show 2 or more column, example like select id_member,nama from member; The program will show id_member only instead of id_member and nama. The program will just run when I select the first column in CSV only.

here is the example :
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs8zb.png)

Comment: Is this because the SQL statement contains a ',' which messes with the CSV parsing code? If that's the case, the SQL statement should be within double quotes, so that the CSV parser ignores the embedded ','.

Comment: Please provide an example of your input data and a detailed description of what goes wrong including the exception or error. If any line numbers are quoted, please show us which line that is (because in general, we can't see your line numbers).

Comment: already add an example input image. the program has no exception error. it's just cant show output when i select more than 2 column.

Comment: It's much easier for people to help you if you include textual content such as code or data files in your post directly and not attached as images.